# Parse xml with simplexml_load_file and insert into MySQL

Tags: php, xml

I am so close to having this work. I have an xml that is not well formed but its the standard among Android Launchers so I have to figure out how to work with it.

I have it loading in my MySQL table but its loading ALL items for ALL categories. Let me show you what i mean.

```
<resources>
<version>1</version>
<category title="System" />
<item drawable="bluetooth" />
<item drawable="bluetooth_audio" />
<item drawable="browser" />
<item drawable="calculator" />
<item drawable="calendar" />
<item drawable="call_history" />
<item drawable="camera" />
<item drawable="clock" />
<item drawable="cmas" />
<item drawable="contacts" />
<item drawable="downloads" />
<item drawable="email" />
<item drawable="gallery" />
<item drawable="help" />
<item drawable="mailbox" />
<item drawable="messaging" />
<item drawable="phone" />
<item drawable="settings" />
<item drawable="supersu" />
<item drawable="superuser" />
<item drawable="superuser_koush" />
<item drawable="voice_commands" />
<item drawable="voice_search" />
<category title="Misc" />
<item drawable="apps" />
<item drawable="apps2" />
<item drawable="bigdx_clean" />
<item drawable="iconback" />
<item drawable="iconfront" />
<item drawable="text_apps" />
<item drawable="text_market" />
<item drawable="text_phone" />
<item drawable="text_sms" />
<item drawable="text_web" />
</resources>
```

Here is the PHP code that is currently parsing it

```
$apps =  simplexml_load_file($ptmpName);

    //loop through parsed xmlfeed and print output
    foreach ($apps->category as $category) {
        printf($category['title']);
        $current_category = $category['title'];
        foreach ($apps->item as $item) {
            printf($item['drawable']);
            $current_drawable = $item['drawable'];
            //insert into databse
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_drawable (user_ip, category,name)VALUES ('$ip',\"$current_category\",\"$current_drawable\")")
            or die(mysql_error());
            //show updated records
            printf ("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
        }
    }
```

So im ending up with all the item drawable entires duplicated for all category titles.

I need item drawable to match to category above it. everytime the category changes down the file the item drawable's row should change category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside second foreach you are reading all items then again the above foreach will run and will give same item which makes them twice.
Use this:**`EDITED`**

```
 $file="filename.xml";
    $apps =  simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach($apps->children() as $child) {
    $xobj=$apps->getName();
//  echo  $xobj. "  =>".$child."<br>";
    foreach($child->attributes() as $attrc => $attrValc) {
        $childc=$child->getName();
        if($childc == 'category'){
    echo  $childc ."  ".$attrc." =>".$attrValc."<br>";
        }else{
            echo  $attrc." =>".$attrValc."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This does stop the duplication of drawables problem but all drawables are getting inputed with system category. drawable category should change when category changes

Comment: Sorry, i got the error fixed. but where do i put my query and what variables to user to get into my sql server?

Comment: it displays great but cannot figure out how to get it into my table. the category should be in same row as drawable under it. when category changes it should change for drawable row

Comment: Thank you very much. got this working with this query  mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_drawable (user, category,name) VALUES ('$user','$category','$attrValc')");